# Mac Keyboard cleaning

Tags: cleaning, technology

My mac keyboard is dirty after a year of using it and I want to clean it, however nothing seems to work. I've tried alcohol (98%) , I've tried soap,nail polish remover, wipes for cleaning glasses... still no result. Anyone know of some other ways? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: What type of dirt are you trying to clean off? Fingerprints or body oils can be cleaned one way; random glopped foodstuffs might need another, and if the plastic itself is becoming discolored, it might not be cleanable at all. Can you clarify in your question? Sometimes a picture helps.

Comment: It may be scratches on the keys or rubbed-off letters, as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Is it filled with dirt or is it just dust compiling on top of the surface of the keyboard?

Try using compressed air - flip your MacBook upside down and use the compressed air to push out the dirt or even the dust. I have tried this and it works perfect for me! BUT DO NOT BLOW TO CLOSELY! This will damage the inside...I had a friend who ruined his macbook by applying directly to the keyboard.

GOODLUCK!

Answer (score 0):

Two answers:

1. Wash it in a kitchen sink running hot water over it, and using a cheap 1" chip brush to scrub between and under the keys.

[image: chip brush]

2. Throw it in a dishwasher, face down.

Swing it with your arm outdoors to get the water out, then dry thoroughly.

Comment: These are awful ideas. Don't do them.

Comment: because?  Are Mac keyboard different?  I've washed and dried at least a dozen keyboards, no problems.

Comment: Maybe some keyboards can survive this kind of treatment, but it's still not a good idea, and there's always the risk that you'd damage components or not get it fully dry. [one](http://www.daskeyboard.com/blog/how-to-clean-your-keyboard-dont-use-the-dishwasher/)

Comment: doesn't answer the question whether Mac kb is different.  Keyboards are nothing but switches.  http://www.explainthatstuff.com/computerkeyboards.html

Comment: First off, it's possible that OP is talking about a laptop keyboard or a wireless keyboard, so this discussion may be moot. Secondly, Mac keyboards, like other modern keyboards, have many other components like LEDs and circuit boards.

Answer (score -1):

Apple recommend take destilled water and a microfibre cleaning tissue. I try it. It work's great - much better than alcohol.

You can use it to clean display too.

Answer (score -1):

If it's just dust, try Blu-Tac.

If it's sticky, then use a soft cloth, spray Colin over the cloth, and wipe it off.